# Search Last Four Numbers in a Given Number

Tags: search, solr4

I am trying to search and match last four numbers against a 10 digit number.

Example

> - 7154226465
> - 7152436464
> - 7152348464

If I search for 646, it should match first two numbers. To be precise, I am looking for suffix search that matches against last 4 digits of indexed number. Below is the schema

```
<fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
         <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateWords="0" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
            <!--<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="17"/>-->
             <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="7" maxGramSize="10" side="front"/>
            <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>

         </analyzer>
         <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateWords="0" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>            
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />    
         </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

EdgNGram with `side="back"` does not works in lucene 4.4. I am using solr v4.9.1

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to search for the last 4 digits, then going for a `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` is the way to go. Try this:

```
<filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>

<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="4" />

<filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
```

A small note. Besides the use of ngrams, a traditional approach to efficiently support leading wildcards is to reverse the string and do a prefix query.